# Square of finite sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

For some fixed function $f(x;\theta)$ with support $\mathcal{X}$ such that $f(x;\theta)>0$ $\forall x\in\mathcal{X}$ and $\forall\theta\in\Theta$,and $\forall\epsilon>0$, $|f(x;\theta^*)-f(x;\check\theta)|>\epsilon$  can I assume that $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{f(x_i;\theta^*)}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{f(x_i;\check\theta)}\right)^2$$ implies that $\theta^*=\check\theta$?

Comment: No more than you can with any other summation in a simpler context. This basically amounts to looking at

$$\left( \sum a_n \right)^2 = \left( \sum b_n \right)^2$$

and wondering if it means $a_n = b_n$.

Comment: Sorry - I added the assumption that $(f(x;\theta^*)-f(x;\check\theta)|>\epsilon$. Does this change things?